# How to check if specific Object element (not property) exists in an Array?

Tags: javascript

I tried using .includes() method but I can't get it to work.

```
data = [{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "TSLA",
        "02. open": "256.7100",
        "03. high": "260.4800",
        "04. low": "254.5100",
        "05. price": "260.1700",
        "06. volume": "4967930",
        "07. latest trading day": "2019-07-23",
        "08. previous close": "255.6800",
        "09. change": "4.4900",
        "10. change percent": "1.7561%"
    }
}]

data.includes("Global Quote") ? console.log("found") : console.log("not 
found");
```

console logs "not found" every time...

Comment: It will show not found because you're comparing `string` against the `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if the array contains atleast one object that has a certain property, you can use `some`

Example with property found:

```js
var data = [{
  "Global Quote": {}
}]

data.some(o => "Global Quote" in o) ? console.log("found") : console.log("not found ");
```

Example with no property found:

```js
var data = [{
    "Not Global Quote": {},
  },
  {
    "Not Global Quote Also": {},
  }
]

data.some(o => "Global Quote" in o) ? console.log("found") : console.log("not found ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't at the correct level in your object while checking for the property with `data.includes(...)`.

You have to get one level deeper and check for the property with [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method.

Your code will look something like this:

```js
const data = [{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "TSLA",
        "02. open": "256.7100",
        "03. high": "260.4800",
        "04. low": "254.5100",
        "05. price": "260.1700",
        "06. volume": "4967930",
        "07. latest trading day": "2019-07-23",
        "08. previous close": "255.6800",
        "09. change": "4.4900",
        "10. change percent": "1.7561%"
    }
}]


data[0].hasOwnProperty('Global Quote') ? console.log('found') : console.log('not found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're going to have more than one object in that array you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const data = [{
  "Global Quote": {
    "01. symbol": "TSLA",
    "02. open": "256.7100",
    "03. high": "260.4800",
    "04. low": "254.5100",
    "05. price": "260.1700",
    "06. volume": "4967930",
    "07. latest trading day": "2019-07-23",
    "08. previous close": "255.6800",
    "09. change": "4.4900",
    "10. change percent": "1.7561%"
  }
}];

function findKey(arr, key) {
  return arr.some(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0] === key);
}

console.log(findKey(data, 'Global Test'));
console.log(findKey(data, 'Global Quote'));
```